# how to set the updated value in searched field by default after updation in angularjs ui-select directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular6, laravel-5.7, angular-ui-select

I am facing problem in angularjs ui-select directive. It works fine, it shows me full data in dropdown. When I select a value from search field and want to update it the it is updated but it can't show by default in the search field. I have to manually search again to see the updated value. Let me paste the code...

Here is the angularjs code

```
$scope.consignee = [];
$http.get("get-consignee", {
 }).then(function(response){

 $scope.consignee = response.data;
 //$scope.consignee.selected = $scope.consignee[0];
 });
```

Here is the ui-select code

```
 <ui-select ng-model="consignee.selected" theme="select2">

 <ui-select-match placeholder="Select Consignee">

    <% $select.selected.CONSIGNEE_NAME %>

 </ui-select-match>

 <ui-select-choices ng-repeat="e in consignee | filter: $select.search">

   <div><% e.CONSIGNEE_NAME %></div>

 </ui-select-choices>

 </ui-select>
```

Let say I have 5 consignee names in dropdown like!

```
 1. hamad
 2. test2
 3. yasin Gul
 4. hamid
 5. munir
```

So the problem is when I use this `$scope.consignee.selected = $scope.consignee[0];` then at `0` index it gives me `hamad` name after updation even if I update `test2` or `yasin Gul` it gives me `hamad` by default set in search field. I know I have `0`,`1`,`2`,`3`,`4` indexes but I want it dynamic not manual. And I want to set only that name which I update. If I update `test2` so that it should give me `test2` by default set in searched field after updation and same for `yasin Gul` etc.. Any help would be appreciated Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cons_id` is your selected database id.

```
$scope.consignee = [];
$http.get("get-consignee", {
 }).then(function(response){

 $scope.consignee = response.data;
 var index = $scope.consignee.findIndex(x => x.CONSIGNEE_ID==cons_id); // use this
 $scope.consignee.selected = $scope.consignee[index]; 
});
```